# Why are hints not generated on surviving Cassandra nodes?

Tags: cassandra

we have 3 nodes `cluster` and have `keyspace` with 3 `RF`.One of the node goes down due to hardware issue but we observed hints are not generating on surviving nodes.

---

The max_hint_window_in_ms parameter value is set to 30 min and `gc_grace_seconds` is set to `default( 10 days)`.

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Hints will only be generated for `max_hint_window_in_ms`. After that time, the coordinators will no longer generate hints nodes which are down or unresponsive.

Hints will only be generated again when the problematic node comes back online. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Erick for update.                                                                                                              
In my case Hints are not generating even before the expiration of max_hint_window_in_ms. Any idea why it is happening. Thanks!

Comment: There won't be hints generated during `max_hint_window_in_ms` if there are no new writes coming into the cluster. Cheers!

Comment: I tried to insert and delete into dummy table but no hints generated for it.

Comment: As I stated in my answer, hints won't get generated again until the problematic node comes back online. Cheers!

Comment: Let me put my case again, It seems some gap is there. This is the sequence.                                                                               a) 3 node cluster with keyspace having 3RF    b)                                                           one node goes down                                                                                                     c) Hints should generate now for DML opreations but it isn't generating and the max_hint_window_in_ms window isn't expired yet.                                                                                     Thanks.